# Keyboard hook doesn't detect barcode scanner input sometimes

Tags: c#, excel, hook, add-in, barcode-scanner

I am using excel-addin project type. this project is all about scanning the qr code using barcode scanner or intercepting the qr code input to the application.
For this purpose I am using KeyPressEventHandler KeyPress.
this sometimes detects the gun input and sometimes don't.
I am stuck and not able to fix this.  Can't understand why this happens?

No error is thrown.

finalstring holds the scanned input.

```
private void SubscribeGlobal() {
    Unsubscribe();
Subscribe(Hook.GlobalEvents());

}
private void Unsubscribe() {
    if (m_Events == null) return;
    m_Events.KeyPress -= HookManager_KeyPress;
    m_Events.Dispose();
    m_Events = null;
}

private void Subscribe(IKeyboardMouseEvents events) {
    m_Events = events;
    m_Events.KeyPress += HookManager_KeyPress;
}

private void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (!scanReaderInputTimer.Enabled) {
        scanReaderInputTimer.Start();
    }
    finalString = finalString + e.KeyChar;
}
```

the KeyPressEventHandler KeyPress should get fired evertime.

Comment: The failure of KeyPress usually happens when there is no focus on a location.

Comment: hi Edney, that's correct but in my case I am intercepting the scanner WITHOUT having focus.
8 out of 10 machines it works. but not always.

Comment: This may be helpful. [Low-Level Keyboard Hook in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/)